# how can I change the typography of my write up to looks nicer in Singapore theme?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am using Singapore theme but I would like to change the defaul fault.
How could I change fonts/typography to make the presentation/frame look nicer/more professional?

Comment: What does `nicer/more professional` means?

Comment: Check this link https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf I hope it helps

Comment: What’s appropriate, readable, and attractive depends in part on the topic, the audience, the size and the lighting of the room where the presentation will be given, etc.  We need information before we can offer an opinion.

Comment: Good. I mean how could I change the default font in Singapore theme to another one looking more professional (say like Garamond or Verdana in Word)

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex` or  `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{Verdana}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}

Some text with the Verdana font
\[ y=f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac1x \mathrm{d}x \]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Verdana and XITS Math have fairly different x-heights. Under LuaLaTeX (version MacTeX2015), the fonts' x-heights may be equalized by adding the option `Scale=MatchLowercase` when the fonts are loaded, i.e., by issuing the commands `\setmainfont{Verdana}`, `\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Verdana}`, and `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{XITS Math}`. (Without the first of these three instructions, both fonts' scale seems unnecessarily diminished.)